# Javascript rebuilding a string from an array, loop not iterating

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Working on a case switching function to apply for boot camp.  1 week javascript experience so go easy on me.  I have been able to break apart the string and change the case of each letter. I can increment the index of the string character and turn the array back into the string.  I can even get the push to write more then one character to the newString array when I had errors and the characters were passing through both if/else statements. but I cannot get the loop to iterate through the string. (i used the $ to discover the end of the string, but i have already tried replacing with myString.length+1 and that didn't help.)

```
var newString= [];
var myString =("");

function swapCase(str){
  i=0;
  myString = (str+"$").split("");
  console.log("_________ " );

  character = myString[i];
  //console.log ("char= "+character); 
  //console.log ("new string a " +newString);

  while (character!==myString.length+1){
    i=i+1;
    //newString.push(character);    
    if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
      character = character.toLowerCase();
      newString.push(character);

      console.log ("  new string after if 1= "+newString);
      console.log ("new index number: "+i) ;
      return;
    }
    else {
      character = character.toUpperCase();
      //nextLetter = character;
      //newString.push(nextLetter);
      newString.push(character);

      console.log ("  new string after if2= "+newString);
      console.log ("new index number: "+i) ;
      return;
    }
  }
} 
swapCase("My StRIng");
newString=newString.join('')
console.log("final joined string- "+newString);
```

Outputs:

```
new string after if 1= m
new index number: 1
final joined string- m
```

Comment: w/o the returns I get stuck in the loop of death, but it still only loops through the originally referenced character

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating by checking if character = string length. For example if $==25 will never be true, what you want is

while (i!==myString.length)

Answer (score 0):

**Rebuilding string from array of characters**

```
  let arrayOfCharacters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

  let rebuiltString = ""
  for (let c of arrayOfCharacters) {
      rebuiltString = rebuiltString + c
  }
  console.log(rebuiltString);
```

**Prints out "abcd"**

Comment: Is this somehow different from using `join`?

Answer (score 0):

newString is not declared, and push & join wouldn't work if it was really a String. Push & join would work if it was an array.